# Seeking shapefile of 2km DINTY Tetrad squares for UK?

Tags: shapefile, data, united-kingdom

does anyone know where I can download a shapefile of 2km DINTY Tetrad squares for the UK please?  A google search wasn't very helpful so I thought I'd try here.

A [Tetrad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrad_%28area%29) is derived from the British National Grid, but is not the same as the British National Grid, so this is not a duplicate question.

Comment: Are you sure this data is available for the UK? USA/Canada yes http://www.tetrad.com/maps_and_data/canada/census-boundaries/

Comment: @Mapperz This question almost surely refers not to the company you link to but instead to the [British Ordnance Survey Grid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrad_%28area%29).

Comment: This question is not a duplicate. The question linked as a duplicate is mine and the download containing OSGB grids provided in the answer also happens to my Git repo, so I'm familiar with the data. :-) I can definitely confirm that my repo doesn't contain tetrads, aka [DINTY tetrads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrad_(area)). So the question stands and is perfectly valid - if there is a DINTY tetrad dataset available for download I'd like to know so I can add it to my repo (at which point the question would indeed be a duplicate) ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is a way in QGIS, using the [TomBio plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/TomBio/), to generate tetrad squares for **an area of interest**. More info and youtube tutorials [available here](http://www.tombio.uk/?q=qgis-plugin).

To use this...

- zoom to an area of interest e.g. using a web basemap and the QuickMapServices plugin.
- turn on OTF projection and set to 27700 (OS GB)
- select "Tetrad (2km)", show grid squares
- click on the grid icon which doesn't have a yellow background
- <kbd>Click</kbd> and <kbd>Drag</kbd> on the canvas to select an area

screenshot below...

[image]

this creates a memory layer but you can save it off as a shapefile etc. for later use.

The shapefiles that @charlesroper [compiled on github](https://github.com/charlesroper/OSGB_Grids) - as mentioned in the comment - are really handy, but don't include tetrads (OS have LOTS of grids...)

I find grid generation can be slow if there are lots of cells so this may not be viable to generate the complete OS Tetrad grid, but hopefully it's useful for a specific survey/project